# Python: digital root of a number: it returns None

Tags: python, root, digital

Given a number, add up the digits to get a new number. Add up the digits of that to get another new number. Keep doing this until you get a number that has only one digit. That number is the digital root the given number.

For example, if n = 45893, we add up the digits to get 4 + 5 + 8 + 9 + 3 = 29. We then add up the digits of 29 to get 2 + 9 = 11. We then add up the digits of 11 to get 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, 2 is our digital root.

```py
def sum_digit_root(num):
    n=str(num)
    if len(n)<=1:
        return num

    else:
        sum=0
        for i in range(len(n) ):
            sum+=int(n[i] )

        sum_digit_root(sum)


print('\n---print sum_digit_root(num)   ---------------------------', sum_digit_root(45893))
```

Comment: The else branch has no return statement.

Comment: yes!   changed to ' return   sum_digit_root(sum) '   , now it works.   Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forget the return statement in the `else` branch:

```py
def sum_digit_root(num):
    n=str(num)
    if len(n)<=1:
        return num

    else:
        sum=0
        for i in range(len(n) ):
            sum+=int(n[i] )

        return sum_digit_root(sum)
    #   ^^^^^^
```